# How to force dijit/form/TextBox to update the variable bound to it immediately - binding does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have an

```
<input id="myTextBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" data-dojo-props="value: at(model, myValue)" />
```

When I try to copy the value from `model.myValue` to another `input` (e.g. by

```
window.setInterval(
  function() { document.getElementById("theOtherInput").value = model.myValue; }, 1000);
```

I notice, that the value of `myTextBox` isn't synchronized with `model.myValue` until the `<input>` of `myTextBox` lost focus. I.e. - `theOtherInput` won't be updated unless I leave the input field `myTextBox`.

How to force dojo to synchronize the input with the bound variable with every keystroke? I thought that this should have been the default behavior or at least it should be possible with little effort, but I don't find the right attribute to do it. Any ideas?

The main problem for me is, when I submit the form by the enter key, the `model.myValue` has still the value before the input `myTextBox` got the focus. (and I don't want a hack with `setInterval` - I just want to have dojo doing its job of synchronizing the input with the model)

Comment: use change event

Comment: @BooBerr'ita how should I use the change event here? Copying the value from the input to the model? Then I don't need dojo when I have to program manually what dojo is supposed to do - or what was your suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can get is setting `intermediateChanges` property to `true` and attach an `onChange` event. Something like this:

```
<input id="myTextBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" 
       data-dojo-props="intermediateChanges: true"
       data-dojo-attach-event="onChange: _myOnChange"
       data-dojo-props="value: at(model, myValue)" />
```

Now, inside your widget, the `_myOnChange` function will run with each valuable keystroke or if the content is changed.

```
_myOnChange: function(newValue){
  console.log(newValue);
  document.getElementById("theOtherInput").value = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Great! `intermediateChanges` was what I was looking for - dojo documentation is kind of a bad joke - this attribute isn't even explained, at least not somewhere near `dijit/form/TextBox`, it's just used in an example without even mentioning it